# I am getting an error when creating react app

Tags: reactjs, react-native, npm, yarnpkg

> C:\Users\KARTHIKA\React>npx create-react-app part2 npx: installed 67
> in 6.481s
>
> Creating a new React app in C:\Users\KARTHIKA\React\part2.
>
> Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes. Installing
> react, react-dom, and react-scripts with cra-template...
>
> yarn add v1.22.10 [1/4] Resolving packages... [2/4] Fetching
> packages... info fsevents@1.2.13: The platform "win32" is incompatible
> with this module. info "fsevents@1.2.13" is an optional dependency and
> failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation. info
> fsevents@2.3.2: The platform "win32" is incompatible with this module.
> info "fsevents@2.3.2" is an optional dependency and failed
> compatibility check. Excluding it from installation. [3/4] Linking
> dependencies... warning "react-scripts >
> @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin > tsutils@3.20.0" has unmet peer
> dependency "typescript@>=2.8.0 || >= 3.2.0-dev || >= 3.3.0-dev || >=
> 3.4.0-dev || >= 3.5.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-beta || >= 3.7.0-dev || >= 3.7.0-beta". [4/4] Building fresh packages... [1/4] ⠂ core-js-pure [2/4] ⠂ core-js [3/4] ⠂ ejs error An unexpected error
> occurred: "C:\Users\KARTHIKA\React\part2\node_modules\core-js:
> EPERM: operation not permitted, mkdir
> 'C:\WINDOWS\VSCODE\yarn--1622206646599-0.821274883299961'".
>
> Aborting installation.   yarnpkg add --exact react react-dom
> react-scripts cra-template --cwd C:\Users\KARTHIKA\React\part2 has
> failed.
>
> Deleting generated file... node_modules Deleting generated file...
> package.json Deleting generated file... yarn.lock Done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"C:\Users\KARTHIKA\React\part2\node_modules\core-js: EPERM: operation not permitted, mkdir 'C:\WINDOWS\VSCODE\yarn--1622206646599-0.821274883299961'"

=> looks like you don't have permission

Comment: I was able to create the react app 3 days back just fine then why does it suddenly say I don't have the permission?Any idea?

Comment: Maybe the repository is different from the one you used before ?
Or you used an administrator console ?

Comment: Yes you are right !It works when I create it as an admin although I don't remember doing that as an admin last time! Thank you so much though!!